# Linux shell, PIPESTATUS in a piece of sh -c script

Tags: linux, shell

I have a simple Linux shell script:

a.sh:

```
eadd | echo 'hello world' | tee aa.txt
exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
```

I run from command line:
`sh -c "./a.sh"`
then run:
`echo $?`
to get the return exit code, it is: **127**

If I run:
`sh -c "./a.sh | tee bb.txt; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}"`
then run:
`echo $?`
The result is **0**.

If I run:
`./a.sh | tee bb.txt; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}`,
No `sh -c`.
Then run: `echo $?`
The result is **127**.

Why the exit code when running with `sh -c` is not the exit code of the expected 127?

How do I get the expected result 127 if run `sh -c "./a.sh | tee bb.txt; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}"`?

Comment: This is confused on multiple accounts. `PIPESTATUS` is not available at all in pure `sh` but the double quotes around the `sh -c "..."` cause the parent shell (presumably Bash) to interpolate _its current_ value of `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` before running `sh -c`

Comment: You'll want to edit `a.sh` to add a `#!/usr/bin/env bash` shebang, _and also_ change from `sh -c` to `bash -c`, _and also_ change from double quotes to single quotes to contain code. Also, [think about removing the `.sh` extension entirely](https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/) -- extensions belong on libraries, not executables. (In line with making sure `a` is an executable, it should have `+x` permissions).

Comment: I search for a while about double quotes to single quotes, but I don't understand the difference that double/single quotes how impact the return exit code. Could you pls advice?